# Downloading File from Server uses large amount of CPU and RAM

Tags: android, download

I have used AsyncTask for Downloading list of files from server.

At a time only one file is downloaded and after completion of one file another download starts. But downloading of file makes my application to use large amount of **CPU more than 30% to 50% and also more amount of RAM**.

Please help how to resolve this problem. Can we do any customization so that it use less amount of CPU

Comment: Why shouldn't it? - No seriously if you are doing work it will use CPU and RAM.